# Template node http out return "No response object"

Tags: node-red

Hi I am trying to send the mqtt result to the template node and display on a webpage. The debug node is displaying the correct info but template node is showing "No response object"

[image: Error message]

```
[{"id":"80675ac8.8a62e8","type":"tab","label":"Flow 6","disabled":false,"info":""},{"id":"a6503dec.84a2f","type":"mqtt in","z":"80675ac8.8a62e8","name":"","topic":"Butbutsiksik/TEMP/set","qos":"0","datatype":"json","broker":"a88cde94.d1216","x":200,"y":340,"wires":[["ac6cc3b4.e4de6","e1c05caf.e526a","856a1d5c.fb69f","b1b418b4.618368","135c9ea5.066571"]]},{"id":"6c6bea95.4cd114","type":"ui_gauge","z":"80675ac8.8a62e8","name":"","group":"cac151e3.e2616","order":2,"width":4,"height":4,"gtype":"gage","title":"Humidity ","label":"%","format":"{{value}}","min":0,"max":"100","colors":["#00b500","#e6e600","#ca3838"],"seg1":"","seg2":"","x":740,"y":220,"wires":[]},{"id":"1a4fb7a1.cdbbf8","type":"debug","z":"80675ac8.8a62e8","name":"","active":false,"tosidebar":true,"console":false,"tostatus":false,"complete":"payload","targetType":"msg","x":970,"y":220,"wires":[]},{"id":"ac6cc3b4.e4de6","type":"function","z":"80675ac8.8a62e8","name":"Humidity","func":"return {payload:msg.payload.outdoor1.hum_value};\n\n","outputs":1,"noerr":0,"x":500,"y":280,"wires":[["6c6bea95.4cd114","427dd1ce.7a066","6ed7ebd2.3d05a4"]]},{"id":"e1c05caf.e526a","type":"function","z":"80675ac8.8a62e8","name":"Temp","func":"return {payload:msg.payload.outdoor1.temp_value};\n\n","outputs":1,"noerr":0,"x":490,"y":400,"wires":[["d82c992b.281518","328c0817.8f1698"]]},{"id":"d82c992b.281518","type":"ui_gauge","z":"80675ac8.8a62e8","name":"","group":"cac151e3.e2616","order":1,"width":4,"height":4,"gtype":"gage","title":"Tempertuare","label":"°C","format":"{{value}}","min":"0","max":"40","colors":["#00f900","#e6e600","#ff2600"],"seg1":"","seg2":"","x":710,"y":380,"wires":[]},{"id":"328c0817.8f1698","type":"function","z":"80675ac8.8a62e8","name":"Temp to homebridge","func":"msg.payload= {\"name\": \"outdoor_temp\", \"service_name\": \"temp\", \"characteristic\": \"CurrentTemperature\", \"value\": + msg.payload}\n\nreturn msg ","outputs":1,"noerr":0,"x":740,"y":440,"wires":[["bf534cac.27fe4","1bf08d2d.432e13"]]},{"id":"bf534cac.27fe4","type":"debug","z":"80675ac8.8a62e8","name":"","active":false,"tosidebar":true,"console":false,"tostatus":false,"complete":"payload","targetType":"msg","x":990,"y":400,"wires":[]},{"id":"1bf08d2d.432e13","type":"mqtt out","z":"80675ac8.8a62e8","name":"","topic":"homebridge/to/set","qos":"","retain":"","broker":"a88cde94.d1216","x":990,"y":440,"wires":[]},{"id":"427dd1ce.7a066","type":"function","z":"80675ac8.8a62e8","name":"Hum to Homebridge","func":"msg.payload= {\"name\": \"outdoor_temp\", \"service_name\": \"humidity\", \"characteristic\": \"CurrentRelativeHumidity\", \"value\": + msg.payload}\n\nreturn msg ","outputs":1,"noerr":0,"x":760,"y":280,"wires":[["24cab4.5350354c","1a4fb7a1.cdbbf8"]]},{"id":"24cab4.5350354c","type":"mqtt out","z":"80675ac8.8a62e8","name":"","topic":"homebridge/to/set","qos":"","retain":"","broker":"a88cde94.d1216","x":990,"y":280,"wires":[]},{"id":"45fd890d.07dd38","type":"debug","z":"80675ac8.8a62e8","name":"","active":false,"tosidebar":true,"console":false,"tostatus":false,"complete":"topic","targetType":"msg","x":1140,"y":140,"wires":[]},{"id":"6ed7ebd2.3d05a4","type":"debug","z":"80675ac8.8a62e8","name":"","active":false,"tosidebar":true,"console":false,"tostatus":false,"complete":"false","x":730,"y":320,"wires":[]},{"id":"856a1d5c.fb69f","type":"function","z":"80675ac8.8a62e8","name":"","func":"temp = msg.payload.outdoor1.temp_value\nhum = msg.payload.outdoor1.hum_value\nname = \"'outdoor1'\"\nmsg.topic = \"INSERT INTO `iot_temp_hum` ( `Name`,`Temp`, `Hum`) VALUES (\"+name+\",\"+ temp+\", \"+ hum +\");\"\nreturn msg;\n\n","outputs":1,"noerr":0,"x":490,"y":200,"wires":[["f0e44788.83cbf8"]]},{"id":"b1b418b4.618368","type":"debug","z":"80675ac8.8a62e8","name":"","active":false,"tosidebar":true,"console":false,"tostatus":false,"complete":"false","x":510,"y":140,"wires":[]},{"id":"f0e44788.83cbf8","type":"delay","z":"80675ac8.8a62e8","name":"","pauseType":"rate","timeout":"5","timeoutUnits":"minutes","rate":"1","nbRateUnits":"30","rateUnits":"minute","randomFirst":"1","randomLast":"5","randomUnits":"seconds","drop":true,"x":740,"y":140,"wires":[[]]},{"id":"135c9ea5.066571","type":"template","z":"80675ac8.8a62e8","name":"","field":"payload","fieldType":"msg","format":"handlebars","syntax":"mustache","template":"This is the payload: {{payload.outdoor1.temp_value}} !\n<script>\nconsole.log(\"{{payload.outdoor1.temp_value}}\");\nconsole.log(\"{{payload.outdoor1.temp_value}}\");\n</script>","output":"str","x":620,"y":640,"wires":[["79b57f34.a1fa","4c2575cf.dfb34c"]]},{"id":"79b57f34.a1fa","type":"http response","z":"80675ac8.8a62e8","name":"","statusCode":"","headers":{},"x":890,"y":640,"wires":[]},{"id":"d205b372.06c96","type":"http in","z":"80675ac8.8a62e8","name":"","url":"/test","method":"get","upload":false,"swaggerDoc":"","x":340,"y":640,"wires":[["135c9ea5.066571"]]},{"id":"4c2575cf.dfb34c","type":"debug","z":"80675ac8.8a62e8","name":"","active":true,"tosidebar":true,"console":false,"tostatus":false,"complete":"false","x":810,"y":520,"wires":[]},{"id":"a88cde94.d1216","type":"mqtt-broker","z":"","name":"homebrigde","broker":"192.168.1.37","port":"1883","clientid":"","usetls":false,"compatmode":false,"keepalive":"60","cleansession":true,"birthTopic":"","birthQos":"0","birthPayload":"","closeTopic":"","closeQos":"0","closePayload":"","willTopic":"","willQos":"0","willPayload":""},{"id":"cac151e3.e2616","type":"ui_group","z":"","name":"ESP-32 test board","tab":"b4041307.b0105","order":1,"disp":true,"width":"12","collapse":false},{"id":"b4041307.b0105","type":"ui_tab","z":"","name":"Home","icon":"dashboard","order":2,"disabled":false,"hidden":false}]
```

Answer (score 2):

The `msg` object that flows into a `http-response` object must come from a `http-in` node.

This is because the `http-in` node attaches the HTTP response object to the `msg` object so it can be used to send the reply to the  request.

In your flow you have `msg` objects coming from both a `http-in` and a `mqtt-in` nodes flowing into the `template` node and then on to the `http-response` node.

Any message coming from the `mqtt-in` node will pass through the `template` node and then to the `http-response` node which will fail with the error you are seeing.

You need to remember that the `template` node will not store any state, all of it's input comes from either the context or the incoming `msg` object. If you want to set the content of the `template` from the incoming MQTT message then you will need to store that data in the context and either recover it between the `http-in` node and the `template` node or access the context variables in the `template` node.